# Modying maketitle (removing 'Springer') in the svmono class

Tags: titles, templates

I am using the [svmono template](http://static.springer.com/sgw/documents/72921/application/zip/svmono.zip) from Springer Verlag for a report.

Only problem is that it auto-generates the word 'Springer' on the title page, lower left corner.

Anyone has any idea as to options how to remove/modify the template accordingly? MWE follows:

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\author{John Doe}
\title{How to change your last name}
\subtitle{An enquiry into the origins of common names}
\maketitle

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-4]


\end{document}
```

[image: img]

Comment: The class is for sending stuff to Springer: what's the problem? If they want that text there it is their decision.

Comment: I wanted to use it for a non-springer related report.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to deal with `svmono` in the past, so I'm probably in a charted territory. `:)` The following code uses `xpatch` to patch `\@maketitle` and remove the word *Springer* in the title page:

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@maketitle}{{\Large Springer\par}}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\author{John Doe}
\title{How to change your last name}
\subtitle{An enquiry into the origins of common names}
\maketitle

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

Same idea, now with `etoolbox` instead of `xpatch`:

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{{\Large Springer\par}}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\author{John Doe}
\title{How to change your last name}
\subtitle{An enquiry into the origins of common names}
\maketitle

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

The output has *Springer* no more:

[image: Output]

Comment: Seems like this trick could be useful in many other contexts, too. What do you think of the patching vs editing the style definition directly, as proposed by @Jubobs?

Comment: @ako Well, Paulo's patch is more economical in terms of lines of code than my redefinition is. In practice, it's best to apply a patch, if possible.

Comment: Is that assessment because you leave the actual style intact?

Comment: @ako: the idea behind my code and Jubobs' is basically the same, we modify a specific part of the class at runtime. At the end of the day, I had to know *where* should I apply the patch, which is covered in Jubobs' answer. `:)`

Answer (score 5):

You can just grab the definition of `\@maketitle` from the class file and comment out the relevant lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{\newpage
 \null
 \vskip 2em                 % Vertical space above title.
\begingroup
  \def\and{\unskip, }
  \parindent=\z@
  \pretolerance=10000
  \rightskip=\z@ \@plus 3cm
  {\LARGE                   % each author set in \LARGE
   \lineskip .5em
   \@author
   \par}%
  \vskip 2cm                % Vertical space after author.
  {\Huge \@title \par}%     % Title set in \Huge size.
  \vskip 1cm                % Vertical space after title.
  \if!\@subtitle!\else
   {\LARGE\ignorespaces\@subtitle \par}
   \vskip 1cm                % Vertical space after subtitle.
  \fi
  \if!\@date!\else
    {\large \@date}%          % Date set in \large size.
    \par
    \vskip 1.5em               % Vertical space after date.
  \fi
 \vfill
% {\Large Springer\par}
% \vskip 5\p@
% \large
%   Berlin\enspace Heidelberg\enspace New\kern0.1em York\\
%   Hong\thinspace Kong\enspace London\\
%   Milan\enspace Paris\enspace Tokyo\par
\endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\author{John Doe}
\title{How to change your last name}
\subtitle{An enquiry into the origins of common names}
\maketitle

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-4]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Sweet! I was looking for this in the template but had missed it.

Comment: Splendid ! I always knew that the trick is somewhere in svmono.cls file - but was not able to point to the problem !